# Using ADDRESS() to return the cell found from another formula (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have speadsheet of a column of city names against a row of the same city names with the cells having the distances between them. So you can picture a diagonal of zeros where each city will travel zero distance to get to itself, and the two triangles either side of the diagonal are mirrors of each other with the data they hold.

Now what I am trying to achieve is to find the city nearest to another city.
So at the moment I can successfully find the minimum distance from one city to the next with:
"{=MIN(IF(B2:B19>0,B2:B19))}"

That gets me the minimum no zero distance, but I would like the city name as well, which appears in the furthest left column.

I have tried using this:
"{=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,X)}

Where X= the column offset needed to reach the list of city names on the left.
I have tried putting in the MIN function as stated at the start in the ROW() and COLUMN() functions, but this leads to errors and does not work.

Essentially for the the distance I find I would like to gain the city name of the leftmost column for which that distance is relating to. If anyone can see where I should look next or where I have gone wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using an `INDEX` formula instead (enter as an array, as you did previously):

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,1,MATCH(MIN(IF(B2:D2>0,B2:D2)),B2:D2,0))
```

This has the same caveat as your `MIN` formula above - it will match the first value found. (Note: @barryhoudini's formula below (`=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(SMALL(B2:D2,2),B2:D2,0))`) will actually save you the array entry and is cleaner as well).

[image]

And if you want to use `INDIRECT`, you can use (also entered as an array):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($1:$1),MATCH(MIN(IF(B2:D2>0,B2:D2)),A2:D2,0)))
```

[image]

This uses the first row as the `row_num` argument to `ROW`, matches the `MIN` value and returns the `ADDRESS` of the cell in the first row at the matched value. The address will be something like `$D$1`, and `INDIRECT` will return that value.

Comment: +1 I like the INDEX version......assuming only 1 zero per row, though, you can use SMALL and avoid "array entry" with `=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(SMALL(B2:D2,2),B2:D2,0))`

Comment: @barryhoudini Great point - I'll add that (with proper citations :) ).